# Direct Bixby http requests to localhost

Tags: bixby

The following doesn't seem to work and I just get a 503.

```
config.default.remote.local=http://localhost:8080
```

In the Action.js file:

```
var response = http.getUrl(config.get('remote.local'), { format: 'json'})
```

Is this a cors issue? I also tried my computer's ip instead of localhost but it just times out after a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

Your bixby action JavaScript doen't evaluate on your computer. Instead it evaluates on a bixby server. That means localhost isn't your computer. It's another system, one that you don't control.

Using your IP address might work, if it had a public IP and you enabled appropriate network access, as long as your ISP doesn't block it. It isn't accessible right now, hence the timeout. But there are good security reasons not to go down that road.

I'd recommend setting up your webservice code on a cloud hosting service. For example you might look at AWS, Google Cloud, Heroku, etc. The right choice depends on your budget, skills, and what kind of webservice you're building.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I am utilizing a heroku server but obviously server changes take much longer than utilizing localhost. However, knowing that I cannot use local host lets me not worry about it anymore :)

Comment: If you plan to run the server on your localhost,  tunneling solutions is another option depending on your security limitations and restrictions.

Comment: I tried with tunneling concept and it works for me.

Comment: Agree with previous comments.  I use ngrok to tunnel the request to my local machine.  It's a life saver for iterative development.  https://ngrok.com/

Comment: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.configuring-endpoints#localhost-tunneling